# Elegant way to avoid multiple callbacks for AJAX Gets in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, typescript

So I'm working on an application that requires me to make some AJAX calls to load in some JSON and bind it using KnockoutJS. I found out though that sometimes my AJAX calls would not populate my select elements every time, the AJAXs call would be executed but there would be no select options in the DOM for some of my select elements. I resolved this by implementing callback functions but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of accomplishing this? I feel like there is a better way of achieving this but I'm just missing something. This is what my current viewmodel implementation looks like now:

```
   activate = () => {
        this.refreshMonths(() => {
            this.refreshDays(() => {
                this.refreshYears(() => {
                    this.refreshHeightFeet(() => {
                        this.refreshHeightInches();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        this.isActivated = true;
    }

    refreshMonths(callback: () => any) {
        this._propertyDataValueService.getMonths().done(entities => {
            this.months(entities);
            callback();
        });
    }


    refreshDays(callback: () => any) {
        this._propertyDataValueService.getDays().done(entities => {
            this.days(entities);
            callback();
        });
    }

    refreshYears(callback: () => any) {
        this._propertyDataValueService.getYears().done(entities => {
            this.years(entities);
            callback();
        });
    }

    refreshHeightFeet(callback: () => any) {
        this._propertyDataValueService.getFeet().done(entities => {
            this.feet(entities);
            callback();
        });
    }

    refreshHeightInches() {
        this._propertyDataValueService.getInches().done(entities => {
            this.inches(entities);
        });
    }
```

And here is what my service looks like:

```
export class PropertyDataValuesSerivce {
    private _baseUrl = '/Data/';

    getMonths(): Q.Promise<Array<Models.SelectListModel>> {
        return Q($.getJSON(this._baseUrl + 'GetMonths'));
    }

    getDays(): Q.Promise<Array<Models.SelectListModel>> {
        return Q($.getJSON(this._baseUrl + 'GetDays'));
    }

    getYears(): Q.Promise<Array<Models.SelectListModel>> {
        return Q($.getJSON(this._baseUrl + 'GetYears'));
    }

    getFeet(): Q.Promise<Array<Models.SelectListModel>> {
        return Q($.getJSON(this._baseUrl + 'GetFeet'));
    }

    getInches(): Q.Promise<Array<Models.SelectListModel>> {
        return Q($.getJSON(this._baseUrl + 'GetInches'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the promise, instead of the callback? You could also try `async...await` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to issue the requests in that specific order, or can you do it in parallel? ie:

```
activate = (): Q.Promise<Models.SelectListModel[]> => {
    return q.all([
        this.refreshMonths(),
        this.refreshDays(),
        this.refreshYears(),
        this.refreshHeightFeet(),
        this.refreshHeightInches()
    ]).then(res => {
        this.isActivated = true;
        return res
    })
}
```

Comment: The order is not specific, I will try that option thanks for your suggestion.